# Text Spilling Outside of Div

Tags: html, css, resize

[image]

The screenshot above shows the problem. Unlike the other similar question I don't need this to work for international text. I need this to work for varying screen sizes and varying amounts of text. The text will come from a databse in production, so I can't simply figure out the breakpoint at which the div needs to move down in advance.

The solution I am looking for would first  move the text block below the image, and then resize the text div vertically as necessary to accomidate all the text. JS or CSS solutions are fine.

HTML below:

```
<div class="product">
    <img class="productImg" src="http://placehold.it/300x240">
    <div class="productTxt">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <h3>Price</h3>
        <p>Suspendisse sed fermentum neque, vel rutrum velit. Curabitur eget dolor luctus, sodales felis sed, dapibus justo. 
        Suspendisse in condimentum ante. Sed nec dui tristique, sollicitudin velit eget, ultricies dui. 
        Ut rhoncus ornare urna, quis venenatis velit ornare eu. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
        Etiam ornare sem finibus lectus volutpat, in feugiat elit ultrices. In sed vulputate eros, quis volutpat elit. 
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse nisi libero, posuere nec laoreet quis, viverra et lorem. Duis odio ante, efficitur et felis at, tincidunt interdum ante.
        Quisque vestibulum eu est a egestas. Nunc hendrerit rutrum dui at cursus. Aliquam mollis nec magna ac mattis. 
        Nam nec est tincidunt leo facilisis finibus non nec mauris. Vestibulum rutrum tristique tincidunt. </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.product {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 330px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #16A085;
}

.productImg {
    width: 240px;
    height: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.productTxt {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: calc(100% - 270px);
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid blue;
 }
```

I can't really remove the relative positioning from the `productTxt` div without breaking the positioning of another element that is within the same div (which I have removed for simplicity in this example)

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is possible in pure CSS, but it's easy with a little JS assistance. For each `.productTxt` div, compare its clientHeight to its scrollHeight. If the scrollHeight exceeds the clientHeight then you know its overflowed, and you can apply a class to the parent `.product` div to juggle the display, height and width properties of the `.productTxt` div, and, if you wish, the `.product` div.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the fixed height in of parent div `.product` and add a `min-width` to `.productTxt`. If you use `100%` for `width` or `height`, it's relative to the parent div, and you must specifically set the parent's `width` or `height`. That's why your `height: 100%` on `.productTxt` was not changing based on your content and was fixed to parent div `.product`'s `height: 330px`.

```
.product {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #16A085;
}

.productTxt {
    box-sizing: padding-box;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: calc(100% - 270px); 
    min-width: 220px; /* change this to what you want */
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid blue;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

To move the text block below the image remove `display: inline-block;` from `.productTxt` class.
If you want to keep the height of `.product` class fix then adjust height of `.productTxt` according to `.product` class and give css `overflow: auto;` to `.productTxt` all you data will displayed with scroll panel,so your HTML is

```
<div class="product">
     <img class="productImg" src="http://placehold.it/300x240">
     <div class="productTxt">
         <h1>Title</h1>
         <h3>Price</h3>
         <p>Suspendisse sed fermentum neque, vel rutrum velit.   
            Curabitur eget dolor luctus, sodales felis sed, dapibus  
            justo.Suspendisse in condimentum ante. Sed nec dui  
            tristique,sollicitudin velit eget, ultricies dui. 
            Ut rhoncus ornare urna, quis venenatis velit ornare eu.       
            Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et  
            malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
            Etiam ornare sem finibus lectus volutpat, in feugiat elit   
            ultrices. In sed vulputate eros, quis volutpat elit. 
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
            Suspendisse nisi libero, posuere nec laoreet quis, viverra  
            et lorem. Duis odio ante, efficitur et felis at, tincidunt  
            interdum ante.  
            Quisque vestibulum eu est a egestas. Nunc hendrerit rutrum   
            dui at cursus. Aliquam mollis nec magna ac mattis. 
            Nam nec est tincidunt leo facilisis finibus non nec  
            mauris.Vestibulum rutrum tristique tincidunt.
        </p>
       </div>
</div>
```

And your CSS will be

```
.product {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 550px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #16A085;
}

.productImg {
    width: 240px;
    height: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.productTxt {
   box-sizing: border-box;
   vertical-align: top;
   height: 230px;
   width: calc(100% - 270px);
   padding: 10px;
   text-align: center;
   position: relative;
   border: 2px solid blue;
   overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: If you don't want to use height then remove height from .product and .productTxt class but it will expand and shrink according to data getting from database